# How to hide data notification from my phone

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

How to hide the data notification from my phone, I want to trigger the OnNotificationReceived function in background and killed state so, am sending a data and notification message to my app.In my case only the notification want to display and the data doesn't but now these two are showing . the purpose of data is only trigger the OnNotificationReceived function in my case.

Please Help me

Comment: You need to send a data message instead of notification message, take a look at - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: Hi, have you solved it ?